# Perl's Hash of Hashes equivalent implementation for dict of dicts in Tcl

Tags: dictionary, hash, nested, tcl

I have a very large file that contains data like below:

```
*1 RES L1 N1 0.32
*22 RES L2 N2 0.64

*100 CAP A1 B1 0.3
*200 CAP A2 B1 0.11

*11 IND K1 K2 0.002
*44 IND X1 Y1 0.00134

... and so on
```

For such files (let us assume the above data is in a file called "example.txt"), I can easily create a Hash of Hashes in Perl and pass these nested Hashes to otherr parts of my Perl program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(FILE,"<", "example.txt") or die "Cannot open file:$!";
if (-f "example.txt") {
 while(<FILE>) {
  chomp;
  if(/^\s*(\S+)\s+(RES|CAP|IND)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*$/) {
   $hoh{$1}{$2}{$3}{$4} = $5;
  }
 }
 close FILE;
}
```

What is a similar way to create a Tcl Hash of Hashes (or rather Dictionary of Dictionaries)?

I tried a small piece of code setting the dict like below (not printing the full code here, to keep focus on the problem):

```
  ...
  set dod [dict create]

  if [regexp {^\s*(\S+)\s+(RES|CAP|IND)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*$} $line all id type x y elemValue] {
   dict set dod $id $type $x $y $elemValue
  }
```

But that does not seem to work. I tested it like below:

```
foreach id [dict keys $dod] {
 if [dict exists $dod "RES"] {
  puts "RES KEY EXISTS"
 } else {
  puts "RES KEY NOT FOUND"
 }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem is a stray slash in the beginning of the regular expression.

To answer the question: a multi-key dictionary *is* a "hash of hashes". Every key adds a new level of dictionaries.

```
dict set foo aa bb cc 1
```

sets the member `{cc 1}` in a dictionary which is the value of the member `{bb ...}` in the dictionary which is the value of the member `{aa ...}` in `foo`.

If you *don't* want a multi-level dictionary and still need to use several key values, you need to do:

```
dict set foo [list aa bb cc] 1
```

Also, I don't know how much is simplified away in your example, but the code to add an item could be better stated as:

```
if {[lindex $line 1] in {RES CAP IND}} {
    dict set dod {*}$line
}
```

But if you want to check existence by e.g. "RES", you need to set it as the top-level key, which you don't in your example (the items in the first column become top-level keys). Initializing as above, the value of `dod` is

```
*1 {RES {L1 {N1 0.32}}} *22 {RES {L2 {N2 0.64}}} *100 {CAP {A1 {B1 0.3}}} *200 {CAP {A2 {B1 0.11}}} *11 {IND {K1 {K2 0.002}}} *44 {IND {X1 {Y1 0.00134}}}
```

so you do get a dictionary, but `dict exists $dod RES` is still necessarily false. By using

```
if {[lindex $line 1] in {RES CAP IND}} {
    dict set dod {*}[lrange $line 1 end]
}
```

(i.e. all the items in the line after the first as keys, except the last which becomes the value) you get the dictionary

```
RES {L1 {N1 0.32} L2 {N2 0.64}} CAP {A1 {B1 0.3} A2 {B1 0.11}} IND {K1 {K2 0.002} X1 {Y1 0.00134}}
```

in which you can test for the existence of "RES".

Going back to the dict-of-dicts

```
*1 {RES {L1 {N1 0.32}}} *22 {RES {L2 {N2 0.64}}} *100 {CAP {A1 {B1 0.3}}} *200 {CAP {A2 {B1 0.11}}} *11 {IND {K1 {K2 0.002}}} *44 {IND {X1 {Y1 0.00134}}}
```

you can check for "RES" by examining each of the sub-dictionaries until you find one that has that key:

```
set found 0
dict for {key subdict} $dod {
    if {[dict exists $subdict RES]} {
        set found 1
        break
    }
}
```

Documentation:
[dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm)

Comment: Peter, sorry there was a mistake in my copy/paste in the original question. For the Tcl part, the regex should have been:  ` if [regexp {^\s*(\S+)\s+(RES|CAP|IND)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*$} $line ...`

Comment: If you're doing something truly complicated with querying the data, dumping it into an in-memory SQLite database is easy.

Comment: Hi Donal,  Is there some documentation on how to use Tcl with in-memory SQLite? I want to try it to see if I can use that solution going forward. Thanks.

Comment: @user3512999: I don't know what the best documentation is, but have you looked here: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/SqliteCmd/sqlite3.htm

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly same but somewhat similar:

```
set data "*1 RES L1 N1 0.32
*22 RES L2 N2 0.64

*100 CAP A1 B1 0.3
*200 CAP A2 B1 0.11

*11 IND K1 K2 0.002
*44 IND X1 Y1 0.00134
"

set pattern {\s*(\S+)\s+(RES|CAP|IND)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)?\s*$}
set result [regexp -all -line -inline -- $pattern $data]

if {[llength $result] == 0} {
    puts "Not found"
    exit 1
}

array set my_data {}
foreach {all ind_0 ind_1 ind_2 ind_3 ind_4} $result {
    set my_data($ind_0)($ind_1)($ind_2)($ind_3) $ind_4
}
puts [parray my_data]
```

Sample output:

```
my_data(*1)(RES)(L1)(N1)   = 0.32
my_data(*100)(CAP)(A1)(B1) = 0.3
my_data(*11)(IND)(K1)(K2)  = 0.002
my_data(*200)(CAP)(A2)(B1) = 0.11
my_data(*22)(RES)(L2)(N2)  = 0.64
my_data(*44)(IND)(X1)(Y1)  = 0.00134
```

Comment: Note that this isn't a "hash of hashes", but a single-level associative array with a complex key.

Comment: Note that Tcl does not support multi-dimensional keys.  the key for the first item above is `*1)(RES)(L1)(N1`.   It still works, but the format used implies some functionality that does not exist.  I would use a different separator than `)(`.  Commas, dashes, periods are good.  If the keys need to be sorted, the key format should be chosen carefully.